# Tab change removes event listener asp.net

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

I'm working on a project in asp.net.  I'm relatively new to it, so this may be a no-brainer that I just can't figure out for some reason.

I have a `<asp:tabcontainer>` element.  Inside one of the tabs there is a checkbox.  I have a jQuery  event listener to do something when it is checked.  When I go to a different tab, and then back to the one with the checkbox, nothing happens when I click on it.  I checked event listeners on it in Chrome and found that the event listener for the click event is removed when I come back to the first tab!  This may be standard asp.net behavior, but I just can't figure out why this is.

Comment: Come on, don't be so shy. Show us your code. Your big bouncy code. Grrrr.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your listeners are lost after a PostBack, so you need to register them the first time the page is loaded **and** after a PostBack is performed:

```
$(function() {
    function onLoad() {
        $('input[type=checkbox]').change(function() {
            // ... do your work here
        });
    }

    var prm = Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance();
    prm.add_endRequest(function () {
        onLoad();
    });

    onLoad();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Is the tabcontrol using postbacks to switch the tabs? If so rebind the jquery like this

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
       ->Initial binding here<-
    });


    var prm = Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance();

    prm.add_endRequest(function () {
        ->rebind here<-
    });                  

</script>
```

Comment: Worked perfect.  Can only mark one as correct, and Danguilherme was first, but I upvoted yours.  Thanks.